# Numba and multidimensions additions - not working with numpy.newaxis?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, subtraction, numba

Trying to accelerate a DP algorithm on python, numba seemed like an appropriate candidate.

I'm doing a subtraction of a 2D array with a 1D array which delivers a 3D array. I'm then using `.argmin()` along the 3rd dimension to obtain a 2D array. This works just fine with numpy, but doesn't with numba.

Toy code reproducing the issue :

```
from numba import jit
import numpy as np

inflow      = np.arange(1,0,-0.01)                  # Dim [T]
actions     = np.arange(0,1,0.05)                   # Dim [M]
start_lvl   = np.random.rand(500).reshape(-1,1)*49  # Dim [Nx1]
disc_lvl    = np.arange(0,1000)                     # Dim [O]

@jit(nopython=True)
def my_func(disc_lvl, actions, start_lvl, inflow):
    for i in range(0,100):
        # Calculate new level at time i
        new_lvl = start_lvl + inflow[i] + actions       # Dim [N x M]

        # For each new_level element, find closest discretized level
        diff    = (disc_lvl-new_lvl[:,:,np.newaxis])    # Dim [N x M x O]
        idx_lvl = abs(diff).argmin(axis=2)              # Dim [N x M]

        return True

# function works fine without numba
success = my_func(disc_lvl, actions, start_lvl, inflow)
```

Why does not the code above run ? It does when taking out `@jit(nopython=True)`.
Is there a work round to make the following calculation work with numba ?

I've tried variants with numpy repeats & expand_dims, as well as defining explicitly the input types of the jit function without success.

Comment: I believe this happends  because `newaxis` is an alias for `None` and that sort of indexing is not supported yet in numba. You can try to use `reshape`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Ralvi Isufaj. I've tried it out, and unfortunately it doesn't work. I get `TypingError: Invalid use of BoundFunction(array.reshape for array(float64, 2d, C)) with parameters (array(int64, 1d, C))
 * parameterized`


I've replace the line where diff is defined. Again, it worked fine without @jit 
`diff    = disc_lvl - new_lvl.reshape(np.append(np.shape(new_lvl),1))`

Comment: For future reference, when posting about an error please copy the error message you get, it helps a great deal figuring out what's wrong :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things you need to change to make it work:

1. Adding a dimension with `arr[:, :, None]`: for Numba, it looks like `getitem` so prefer using `reshape`
2. Use `np.abs` instead of built-in `abs`
3. The `argmin` with `axis` keyword argument is [not implemented](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/numpysupported.html#calculation). Prefer using loops, which Numba is designed to optimize.

With all this fixed you can run the jitted function:

```
from numba import jit
import numpy as np

inflow = np.arange(1,0,-0.01)  # Dim [T]
actions = np.arange(0,1,0.05)  # Dim [M]
start_lvl = np.random.rand(500).reshape(-1,1)*49  # Dim [Nx1]
disc_lvl = np.arange(0,1000)  # Dim [O]

@jit(nopython=True)
def my_func(disc_lvl, actions, start_lvl, inflow):
    for i in range(0,100):
        # Calculate new level at time i
        new_lvl = start_lvl + inflow[i] + actions  # Dim [N x M]

        # For each new_level element, find closest discretized level
        new_lvl_3d = new_lvl.reshape(*new_lvl.shape, 1)
        diff = np.abs(disc_lvl - new_lvl_3d)  # Dim [N x M x O]

        idx_lvl = np.empty(new_lvl.shape)
        for i in range(diff.shape[0]):
            for j in range(diff.shape[1]):
                idx_lvl[i, j] = diff[i, j, :].argmin()

        return True

# function works fine without numba
success = my_func(disc_lvl, actions, start_lvl, inflow)
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Jacques Gaudin. Your solution worked fine and helped me solve my problem. 

I increased a bit the size of the matrices and observed a computation time decrease of factor 2 vs the non-jitted version of the same function. Does that seem reasonable to you ?

Comment: That's probably as much as you can get since most of your original function is vectorized. If anything, I would look into the operations that produce results of different dimensions and see if a loop version is faster. I don't think there's much to save there but it may be worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Find below the corrected code of my first post, that you can execute with and without jitted mode of the numba library (by removing the line that starts with @jit). I've observed a speed increase of factor 2 for this example.

```
from numba import jit
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt

inflow = np.arange(1,0,-0.01)                       # Dim [T]
nbTime = np.shape(inflow)[0]
actions = np.arange(0,1,0.01)                       # Dim [M]
start_lvl = np.random.rand(500).reshape(-1,1)*49    # Dim [Nx1]
disc_lvl = np.arange(0,1000)                        # Dim [O]

@jit(nopython=True)
def my_func(nbTime, disc_lvl, actions, start_lvl, inflow):
    # Initialize result 
    res = np.empty((nbTime,np.shape(start_lvl)[0],np.shape(actions)[0]))

    for t in range(0,nbTime):
        # Calculate new level at time t
        new_lvl = start_lvl + inflow[t] + actions  # Dim [N x M]      
        print(t)

        # For each new_level element, find closest discretized level
        new_lvl_3d = new_lvl.reshape(*new_lvl.shape, 1)
        diff = np.abs(disc_lvl - new_lvl_3d)  # Dim [N x M x O]

        idx_lvl = np.empty(new_lvl.shape)
        for i in range(diff.shape[0]):
            for j in range(diff.shape[1]):
                idx_lvl[i, j] = diff[i, j, :].argmin()

        res[t,:,:] = idx_lvl

    return res

# Call function and print running time
start_time = dt.datetime.now()
result = my_func(nbTime, disc_lvl, actions, start_lvl, inflow)
print('Execution time :',(dt.datetime.now() - start_time))
```